# escaped html won't unescaped (now: unescaped html won't escape back)

Tags: java, html, character-encoding, apache-commons

So I'm currently using the commons lang apache library.

When I tried unescaping this string: `&#128512;`
This returns the same string: `&#128512;`

```
String characters = "&#128512;"
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(characters);
```

Output: `&#128512;`

But when I tried unescaping a String with a less few characters, it works:

```
String characters = "&#12851;"
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(characters);
```

Output: ㈳

Any ideas? When I tried unescaping this String `"&#128512;"` on [online unescaping utility](http://www.htmlescape.net/htmlunescape_tool.html), it works, so maybe it's a bug in the apache common langs library?  Or can anyone recommend another library?

Thanks.

UPDATES:

I'm now able to unescape the String successfully.  The problem now is when I tried to escaped the result of that unescape, it won't bring back the String (😀).

Comment: Which version of commons lang are you using?

Comment: `unescapeHTML` is according to HTML4.0 (1998)... Supplementary characters (`>0xFFFF`) were first added in Unicode 3.1 (2001). Just find another library that is not as ancient.

Comment: @orique, 2.3.0.v201005080501.

Comment: @mai yeah use `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4` from [commons lang3](http://commons.apache.org/lang/download_lang.cgi)

Comment: @Esailija, can you recommend another library aside from this one from apache?

Comment: @mai Not really, what's wrong with using lang3?

Comment: @Esailija, can you recommend another library aside from this one from apache? Unescaping works fine. But when I tried escaping the characters, it won't go back to &#128512;

Comment: You don't actually need to escape that character in html.

Comment: But there's this scenario, when I need to get escape the output of the unescape

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24041/discussion-between-mai-and-esailija)

Comment: 128512 > 65535 (sizeof short). Unicode is stored as a short

Comment: @LucasEasedUp it still gives me &#128512; even when I used unescapeXml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a unicode character whose index is `U+1F600 (128512)` -  GRINNING FACE

Refer the [URL](http://www.charbase.com/1f600-unicode-grinning-face) for details

The String you have mentioned is HTML Escape of U+1F600, If you unescape it using Apache commons lang it will draw you the required smiley as provided in screenshot

The set of characters from U+0000 to U+FFFF is sometimes referred to as the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP). Characters whose code points are greater than U+FFFF are called supplementary characters. The Java platform uses the UTF-16 representation in char arrays and in the String and StringBuffer classes. In this representation, supplementary characters are represented as a pair of char values, the first from the high-surrogates range, (\uD800-\uDBFF), the second from the low-surrogates range (\uDC00-\uDFFF).

Regarding your update that its not converting back to 😀

You can also represent a character using a Numeric Character Reference, of the form &#dddd;, where dddd is the decimal value representing the character's Unicode scalar value. You can alternatively use a hexadecimal representation &#xhhhh;, where hhhh is the hexadecimal value equivalent to the decimal value.
 A good site for [this](http://www.russellcottrell.com/greek/utilities/SurrogatePairCalculator.htm)

Have added few SoP to help you understand this unicode better.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it will return a smiley since I got the "&#128512;" from an emoji list.  My only problem now is when I tried to escaped now that smiley, it won't give me back the "&#128512;" (I've tried this with StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4().  I'll try this with the translate())

Comment: StringEscapeUtils.ESCAPE_HTML4.translate(smiley) won't give me back the "&#128512;"

Comment: Have updated the answer after your modified question :) , refer the link to know the logic of calculating HTML entity from unicode for surrogates.

Comment: Hi, I think I'm getting close.  What does toCodePointArray() do?

Comment: Refer http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-unicode/ to have understanding. It will help.

Comment: Will check that, once confirmed, I'll start the bounty again (since it's already expired) and marked your answer as the accepted answer. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`unescapeHtml()` leaves `&#128512;` untouched because – as [the documentation](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29) says – it only unescapes HTML 4.0 entities, which are limited to 65,536 characters. Unfortunately, 128,512 is far beyond that limit.

Have you tried using `unescapeXml()`?

XML supports up to 1,114,111 (10FFFFh) character entities ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML)).

Comment: it still gives me &#128512; when I used unescapeXml()

Comment: Oh, sorry. By misreading, I didn't notice that unescapeXml() does not really unescapes *all* entities belonging to the XML 1.0 standard. It only converts the five basic entities: gt, lt, quot, amp, apos.

Answer (score 2):

Well - the solution is pretty easy:
use [org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4%28java.lang.String%29) instead! (unless you're using Java <1.5, which you probably won't)

```
String characters = "&#128512;";
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(characters);
```

Comment: But using StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(unescapedResult) won't bring me back the "&#128512;"

Comment: you surely mean `escapeHtml` for the other direction?

Answer (score 1):

i think the problem is that there is no unicode character `"&#128512;"`
so the method simply returns this string.

the [doc of the function](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml(java.lang.String)) says only

Returns: a new unescaped String, null if null string input

Answer (score 0):

If it's a HTML specific question, then you can just use JavaScript for this purpose.
You can do

> 

```
    escape("&#128512;") which gives you %26%23128512%3B
    unescape("%26%23128512%3B") which gives you back &#128512;
```